# Add and Remove Snapshots with PowerCLI for multiple servers

Tags: virtual-machine, snapshot, powercli

I am trying to get a snapshot from multiple servers with PowerCLI.

```
Connect-VIServer -server 192.168.0.1 -user acconut -password xxx

$vmlist = Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Servers.txt

foreach($VM in $VMlist) {
    New-Snapshot -VM $vm -Name Temp-SnapShot -description (get-date),'Created for patching'
}

Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$false
```

If I delete `get-date`, the script will work. But I need to type date in descriptions. How should I change the Script above to have `Get-Date` in snapshot's descriptions?

Also, I need to delete these snapshot after a couple days:

```
Connect-VIServer -server 192.168.0.1 -user acconut -password xxx

$vmlist = Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Servers.txt

foreach($VM in $VMlist) {
    Remove-Snapshot -VM $vm -snapshot -confirm:$false
}

Disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$false
```

I could not delete snapshot with `Remove-Snapshot` because I get this error:

> Remove-Snapshot : Missing an argument for parameter 'Snapshot'. Specify a parameter of type 'VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.VM.Snapshot[]' and try again.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For your first problem, my guess is that `-Description` only takes a string.  I can show you how to fix that when the question reopens.  For the second part, do you get an error when you try that script?

Comment: Yes,, I am getting 
Remove-Snapshot : Missing an argument for parameter 'Snapshot'. Specify a
parameter of type 'VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.VM.Snapshot[]' and try
again.

Comment: Ah, you will need to get the specific snapshot first, then pass that to `Remove-Snapshot`.

Comment: Why did you close this question?
I was waiting till question reopens.

Answer (score 2):

On the description part you can put `$date = get-date` and `do -description $date`. That should work.

before you can remove the snapshot you need to get the snapshot. I would say edit your remove-snapshot line to include this:

```
Get-Snapshot -VM $vm | Remove-Snapshot -confirm:$false
```

you might even want to add -RemoveChildren:$true ( this will remove "All" snapshots )

Comment: I also have a script to take snapshots using a list of vms in a .txt file. Not sure how to put the whole script here for anyone so if you need access to the script [link](http://justawinadmin.blogspot.com/2014/12/power-cli-script-to-take-snapshots-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should help with what you are looking for.  It finds the snaps and removes any greater than 10 days old.

```
$snaps = Get-VM | Get-snapshot | Select vm,name,created

if ($snaps.created -le (get-date).adddays(-10))
{
  $remsnaps = $snaps | Where {$_.created -le (get-date).adddays(-10)}
  $remsnaps | Out-File "C:\Scripts\RemoveSnaps\logs\remsnapsVC.txt"
  $remobject = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\RemoveSnaps\logs\remsnapsVC.txt"

  $rmsnap = Get-Snapshot $remsnaps.vm
  Remove-Snapshot -Snapshot $rmsnap -RemoveChildren -Confirm:$false #-WhatIf


 $MessageSubject = "The following snaps were removed from NTVCenter01!"
 $MessageBody = $remobject | fl | out-string

 SendEmail

}
```